# For some open set centred around a midpoint $x∈\Bbb R$, can we find an $e>0$ such that $(x - e, x + e) = {x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

If we take e to be arbitrarily small it seems like, because the open ball is open, we can squeeze the set down to the singleton, which, however, is closed, so assuming this is possible gives us that an open set is closed, and the singleton isn't clopen in $\Bbb R$. Not sure how to deal with this further.

Comment: why do you think one could squeeze the set down to the singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $e>0$, the set $(x-e,x+e)$ will never equal the set $\{x\}$. take $x+e/2$. this is in the interval, but it's not in the singleton set. This means that, we can construct intervals of the form $(x-e,x+e)$ as small as we want (by letting $e$ get as small as we want), but there will always be some points in $(x-e,x+e)$ that are not in $\{x\}$